# Error while using time.Parse when timezone and offset are together

Tags: date, parsing, go, time

I have the following code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    date, err := time.Parse("Monday, 2 January 2006 15:04:05 PM MST-07:00" ,"Thursday, 17 August 2020 13:20:00 PM GMT+08:00")
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(date)
}
```

And it fails with the following error :

> 2009/11/10 23:00:00 parsing time "Thursday, 17 August 2020 13:20:00 PM
> GMT+08:00" as "Monday, 2 January 2006 15:04:05 PM MST-07:00": cannot
> parse ":00" as "-07:00"

But it succeeds if I separate MST-07:00 with a space as : "MST -07:00" in both layout sample and actual string.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GMT times undergo special handling by `time.Parse`. The signed offset for GMT in the value must be in the range -23 through +23 excluding zero, and may not include a colon. The layout should just specify `MST` without an offset.

For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    for _, ts := range []string{
        "Thursday, 17 August 2020 13:20:00 PM GMT",
        "Thursday, 17 August 2020 13:20:00 PM GMT+2",
        "Thursday, 17 August 2020 13:20:00 PM GMT-2",
    } {
        date, err := time.Parse("Monday, 2 January 2006 15:04:05 PM MST", ts)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err.Error())
        }
        fmt.Println(date)
    }
}
```

yields the output:

```
crow@mac:tp$ ./example
2020-08-17 13:20:00 +0000 GMT
2020-08-17 15:20:00 +0200 GMT+2
2020-08-17 11:20:00 -0200 GMT-2
```

[An issue was raised for this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9881) a while back, and the outcome was (with reference to an example time string containing `GMT+10:00`):

> The special handling of GMT, which is needed for other things, makes
> it very difficult to know whether the +10:00 should be considered part
> of the time zone or left alone to match the layout.

and so the issue was closed without proposed changes.

Comment: So, basically there is no way of converting my timestamp without truncating its value removing the last :00?

Comment: @MatiasBarrios: There's no way using the standard `time.Parse`, correct. There's nothing to stop someone writing a time parsing function that works differently, of course.